# Review for upvoted question marked as potential spam and was a audit

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6959470) review has a marking I haven't seen before:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review
>   carefully

But nothing in this question seems to hint at spam, so what is causing this flag to be raised?

Also, this review happened to be an audit.

Comment: What is unexpected about review-audits presenting good posts as bad ones?

Comment: @Deduplicator The unexpected part is that it also calls it potential spam - and that doesn't seem to be related to the audit

Answer (score 5):

Some audits will include that warning on posts that are known to be not spam, so that users won't automatically flag all posts as spam just because they see that message; it forces them to actually evaluate the post to see if it really is spam.  This is important because the "real" automated processes are only taking a guess at what they think is spam, and they really do need a human to make sure that it is spam as there are false positives.