# Why did the system identify this audit as possible spam?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, spam

I just passed an audit reviewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939455/why-does-the-value-of-typeof-null-change-inside-a-loop/37948799#37948799). It was an high quality post, and my upvote was appropriate. What's weird is that I was presented this warning:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review
> carefully

Why so? Nothing in the post looked like spam. At first I thought it could have been added to make the audit more difficult, so I searched on Meta for info about such warning, found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267355/why-am-i-getting-our-system-has-identified-this-post-as-possible-spam-in-revie) and learnt that the spam notification is not related to the audit.

Well, now I know that the system actually identified the answer as possible spam, but why?

**This has been closed as duplicate of the post I linked, but note that it isn't:** there, the audit was correctly identified as spam and the OP wanted info about the alert. Here, I have already gotten such info and I am questioning whether the audit was incorrectly identified as spam, or to know why it was. **Update:** the question was reopened. **Update:** the question was closed again as duplicate of the same question, but it is not because of the same reason.

Comment: Not sure how accurate that old information is. This post has had two other audits before yours and neither of those had the spam banner at the top, so it's not the post itself which was identified as spam. An external factor (possibly random) unrelated to the post caused it to appear there.

Comment: @animuson thanks. That's curious, does it mean it's a bug?

Comment: Maybe Reddit links are considered suspicious?

Comment: Doesn't that warning show up at random on audits to make sure you don't flag good posts as spam just because of the banner?

Comment: I am yet to understand why reviewers are expected to identify spam at all. It is a completely different function from reviewing.

Comment: @EJP: Completely different from reviewing *what*? Close/reopen voters are not expected to identify spam, nor (usually) LQP reviewers, but it is the height of absurdity to suppose that suggested edit reviewers should not be paying attention to possible spam suggestions. If not them, who else? And spam detection is in fact one of the primary design goals of FP and LA reviews. (To a lesser extent, Triage as well.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I do not agree. In my opinion it is the height of absurdity to require reviewers to be responsible for identifying spam. Reviewers should be concerned with question & answer quailty, answerability, relevance, etc. Spam is a completely separate issue and it is unfair to the point of preposterousness to *require* volunteers to identify it correctly. In many cases that isn't possible without following a link, which is well above and beyond the call. I gave up reviewing some years ago because of this absurd requirement, and I am not alone.

Comment: @EJP You still vote on questions/answers you see across the site right? Surely that's exactly the kind of ad-hoc volunteer reviewing feature you want. Meanwhile clicking "looks OK" or "no action needed" is explicitly signing-off on the post being appropriate to stick around for along time. Most spam follows one of a handful of preset patterns which those signing-off on it absolutely need to be alert to.

Comment: @EJP: Quite frankly, out of [all the very many duties FP and LA reviewers must handle](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/), checking for spam is one of the easiest and most valuable services, as almost anyone on the Internet has some experience spotting spam. Objecting to that, and not to all the *other* miscellaneous things the queues involve, is pretty silly.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's what I Thought at first, but the meta post I linked suggests that it is not the case

Comment: @NathanTuggy It is *not* easier to identify spam than to identify nonsense, irrelevance, etc., especially if it requires chasing links, which I do not do on this site for any reason whatsoever. and the various tools that can be used to mechanise it are a lot more effective. As in every other discussion I have engaged in on this topic, you comment does not actually address the issue, which is that reviewers should not be *required* to identify spam as a condition of reviewing. If there are low quality reviews, SO should address that issue specifically, e.g. via the voting system, or bans.

Comment: @EJP then the solution is simple, skip. If you aren't, for whatever reason, doing the best effort when reviewing maybe reviewing isn't for *you*. Leave a more motivated reviewer to do the work.

Comment: @gnat The question was already closed as a dup of the post you link. Note that such post was already linked in the original question and I had already expained why I don't think it's a dup (I ma be wrong, though)

Comment: thanks for heads up. Agree it's not a duplicate, retracted my vote

Comment: confusingly, i got the warning on a clearly high quality question that has zero votes, but when i click the questions title, i see the same question with upvotes and an accepted answer. (edit: oh this is a test. duh)

Comment: This might be a better duplicate target: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285444/review-for-upvoted-question-marked-as-potential-spam-and-was-a-audit

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I agree. The answer is unsatisfactory there, but the question is the same indeed

Comment: This happened because that was a test for you. I faced the same type of post while reviewing and it told me that it was just a test.

Comment: Thanks @ArchitGargi. Please see the note after bold text: I am familiar with audits, but normally they check if you are paying attention. So the audit said that I failed to identify the post as spam, and I want to understand why: the post is actually not spam.